# Web access to Gluu v4.0 server, installed on Ubuntu 20 machine

Tags: gluu

I have installed Gluu server version 4.0 on an Ubuntu ver.20 powered machine. After running setup script I am able to login to server from command line and according to Gluu docs I should be able to access UI from web browser using this pattern `https://<hostname-where-gluu-server-installed>.`
But this doesn't work. I have enabled port 443. Both browser and server are on the same machine. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Gluu must be deployed on a server or VM with a static IP Address. The static IP address should resolve to a computer hostname which can be achieved by adding an entry to the DNS server or in `/etc/hosts`.

More information on official Gluu docs:
https://gluu.org/docs/gluu-server/4.0/installation-guide/

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I'll try this later, project was put on hold for the time being.